# Consulta SELECT con filtros

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta en SQL

```
select CLA_TRAB, CLA_EMPRESA from RH_TRAB
where CLA_TRAB = @CLA_TRAB
```

Como puedo hacer para que si @CLA_TRAB viene nulo, me traiga todos los registros de la entidad RH_TRAB.

Comment: `OR @CLA_TRAB IS NULL`

Answer (score 5):

Hay varias maneras:

```
select CLA_TRAB, CLA_EMPRESA from RH_TRAB
where CLA_TRAB = @CLA_TRAB or @CLA_TRAB is null
```

O también:

```
select CLA_TRAB, CLA_EMPRESA from RH_TRAB
where CLA_TRAB = ISNULL(@CLA_TRAB,CLA_TRAB)
```

El problema será cuando la tabla tenga muchos registros porque esto genera problemas de rendimiento ya que genera un escaneo de tabla o índices debido a que ambas condiciones deben comprobarse con cada fila de la tabla
Para tablas con mucha información lo mejor sería lo siguiente:

```
if @CLA_TRAB is not null
 select CLA_TRAB, CLA_EMPRESA from RH_TRAB
 where CLA_TRAB = @CLA_TRAB 
else 
 select CLA_TRAB, CLA_EMPRESA from RH_TRAB
```

*Edición:*

Para mejorar el rendimiento de un parámetro opcional, lo ideal es agregar un hint a la consulta para recompilarla en cada ejecución. Esto permitirá que siempre se utilice un plan óptimo y evitará reescribir código que puede generar errores al tener que mantener dos consultas sincronizadas. El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
select CLA_TRAB, CLA_EMPRESA from RH_TRAB
where CLA_TRAB = @CLA_TRAB or @CLA_TRAB is null
OPTION( RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: Agregué una aclaración para dejar una opción más deseable al momento de programar este tipo de problemas.